# I can't get response using Axios API call from my Nginx Ubuntu(AWS EC2) server

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx, https

I am running a React app for front-end with HTTPS and Node Express for back-end as a proxy in Nginx.

This is my Nginx setting.
(`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`)

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                root /var/www/frontend/build;
                index index.html;
                try_files $uri /index.html;
                expires 30d;
        }               

        location /api {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RS$
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
        ssl_session_timeout 1h;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000" always;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by C$
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by$
}
```

And React app is already built and it works well with HTTPS.
I call an API like `http://example.com/api/v1/check-user` in the front-end side, and my back-end `app.js` looks like:

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import models, { sequelize } from "./models";
import configureRoutes from "./routes";
import ErrorMiddleware from "./ErrorMiddleware";
import { PORT } from "./config";

import RolesService from "./services/Roles";
import StatusesService from "./services/Statuses";
var cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({}));

app.use(cors());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});
const options = {};

sequelize
  .sync(options)
  .then(async () => {
    await sequelize.query('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";');
  })
  .then(async () => {
    const name = "Backend";
    await RolesService.createInitialRoles();
    await StatusesService.createInitialStatuses();
    return models.Companies.findOrCreate({
      where: {
        name,
      },
      defaults: {
        name,
        address1: ...
      },
    });
  })
  .then(() => {
    configureRoutes(app);
    app.use(ErrorMiddleware);
    app.listen(PORT || 5000, () => {
      console.log(`backend is listening on port ${PORT}!`);
    });
  });
```

The weird thing is that calling APIs on my local environment works well including using Postman.
And when I call an API from https front-end, then it causes an error.
[image]

Calling HTTP back-end says:

[image]

And when I use https, it is still causes Network error.

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Unless the browser is logging a message in the devtools console which explicitly mentions CORS, you can safely rule out CORS as the cause of the problem.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thank you. Please let me know in detail. What code should I add or fix.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make your Express API use HTTPS instead of HTTP. As the error in the API Request indicates, requests between an application loaded through HTTPS and an endpoint running on HTTP is not permitted.

Comment: It makes sense, thanks. Then how to implement it? I tried several ways but not sure the correct way.

Comment: There are many ways to do it but the easiest would be to use LetsEncrypt: https://gist.github.com/basharovV/e25989cc918f0b21ded26c8bf3be8400

Comment: By creating a https server, attaching cert and key files, and enabling dot files in express and Nginx worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: And my problem is to force redirect to https the Nginx service. I tried to add `rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;`, `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`, etc, but everything didn't worked for me. They causes to redirect to `Welcome to Nginx` page. How to fix it?

Comment: I suggest you refer to the nginx configuration given in the link above. Maybe you missed a certain part of the configuration if that is the case.